# Chrome - how to get new tab and startup to show blank pages?

Tags: google-chrome

How can I set new tab pages and browser startup pages to be blank in Chrome? The default page takes a while (5 - 10 seconds) to become usable. Not *really* a big deal, but annoying when browsing rapidly.

A couple more points:

- I tried setting the startup webpage in Chrome settings, but this only affects the page displayed on browser startup, not pages displayed on new tab.
- I would rather not use extensions that merely clean the UI DOM after the page is initialized. The issue here is not visual display of the new tab page, but the delay in setting it up.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, if this extension cleans the UI, after the new tab was opened, but I don't think so.

So I would recommend you to use the [Empty New Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij)-Extension from Google Chrome.

Comment: That seems to work. The latency is a bit more acceptable now. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to use extension for this. Check my answer.